# Python dict automatically converting list-type values to simple objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, django-rest-framework

I'm facing a strange problem with python dictionary.

[image]
expanding `file` key-value pair:
[image]
As you can clearly see above that inside my request data dictionary, I have an object named `file` which is a `list` (of file objects).
When I try to get this object, I get the actual file object located at index `0`.

Even the type shows that it's an object rather than a list. Why is that behaviour?

`type(request.data['file'])`

> django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile

I tried extracting this perticular key,value pair but I still get the value as an object rather than a list which is not what i want.

```
{k:v for k,v in request.data.items() if k in ['file']}
Out[16]: {'file': <InMemoryUploadedFile: irreg-total2.jpg (image/jpeg)>}
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour? 
I'm using python 3

Comment: Please do not put imgaes rather txt data , easy to read and reproduce, What is your dataset like CSV/json/xlx?

Comment: it is a json object.

Comment: The two main images are just a snapshot of live request taken in debug mode and it won't make a difference if try and put it in text.

Shame that people downvote without even understanding the question.

Comment: @saran3h there _is_ a huge differences between posting a link to an image and posting text contained in the answer, which is that in the first case if the image is no longer online the question doesn't make any sense anymore, while text will remain part of the post (obviously). Also, the text in your image cannot be indexed by search engines. Please remember that SO is not a forum but a technical knowledge base, the point here is that people having the same problem can find the question and the answer. Also, text is much more readable.

Comment: what exactly is present in these images which need indexing from search engines? you are not understanding the context of these images and why I deliberately not posted the actual text. because it doesn't make a difference at all and it is rather appropriate to have image here.

Answer (score 2):

`data['file']` is not list. It is a single instance of `InMemoryUploadedFile` as indicated by `{InMemoryUploadedFile}`.

`<class 'list'>: [<InMemoryUploadedFile: ireg-totla2.jpg (image/jpeg)>]` is just the representation of that object (as returned from `__repr__()` method.

See `UploadedFile.__repr__()` method on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/#InMemoryUploadedFile

Compare that to rest of the elements in `data` dict

Comment: what if I had multiple `<InMemoryUploadedFile>` objects as values? Will it then show the `type` of `data['file']` as `list`? 

I need to have the `data['file']` as a list of `<InMemoryUploadedFile>` no matter how many objects are there. looking for a clean solution to do that .

Comment: That depends on how `data` dict is created and in particular how `data['file']` value is set. You don't show any code that do that, so it's not possible to tell anything.